# Understanding MCTS node selection

Tags: algorithm, montecarlo

I'm currently trying to implement MCTS for a project of mine but I'm not sure if I understand the idea of node selection correctly. In the beginning of the game, after I randomly select one move, unwind the whole tree to the point of a game end and then do the backpropagation, this node is obviously seen as better than all the other ones since it's 1/1 (if we got the win) vs. their 0/0. How does the MCTS flee that trap and not get stuck with the one, randomly selected, node?

I mean, if we use, say, UCB for finding the best node to expand, it'll always choose the node we selected first (given it resulted in a win) completely ignoring all the other ones since it'll be the only one non-zero valued. What am I missing here, since it's obviously not the case?

Answer (score 8):

Each time you are at a node, you expand a node according to these rules :

- if a child node has never been expanded before, then expand one of the unexplored child at random (and you can immediately unwind from this child node)
- otherwise, each child node has been visited at least once. Compute for all of them the "exploration/exploitation" value and expand the child node with highest value

The idea of MCTS is maximizing the exploration/exploitation. If a child node has never been explored before, the "exploration" value associated with it is infinite, you will have to explore it. However, once you have expanded all child nodes, then you will expand more frequently the child nodes with higher value (this is the "exploitation" part)